# iPhone 5S overheating with very short battery life

Tags: battery, iphone

I have done my research, and have found no solutions to my phone overheating. I've had the phone since July 2014, and I really started to notice that the phone over heated a lot in January 2015, and the battery life getting shorter and shorter.

Today in fact, my phone got so hot it was actually that hot that I couldn't really touch it. In the last few hours it has been hot, and has not cooled down. There are about 2 apps running on my phone: Settings and Safari.

Comment: Did you already reinstall your phone from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery in your phone is dying. Continuing to use it and charge it could cause it to catch on fire. You can take it to Apple to be repaired/replaced but will probably cost a lot as it is an older phone or you can take it to a local phone "fix-it" place to have the battery replaced.

It looks like [https://www.batteriesplus.com](https://www.batteriesplus.com/repair/cell-phone/apple/iphone-5s-_-a1453-_-a1530-_-a1533/ris10339) will replace it fot $60 or you could go the [ifixit route](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+5s+Battery+Replacement/19239) and do it yourself.

I do recommend that you replace the battery soon, I had a 3GS years ago with the exact same symptoms, the battery eventually expanded so much it broke the back of the phone and could not be repaired.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I cannot replace it though, as I'm in a contract with my carrier, and it expires next October

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding, I have updated the answer to clarify my recommendation to replace the battery not the entire phone